# Relation between Jenkins and Nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

Can someone please let me know what is the relation between Jenkins and Nexus. I'm new to this area so pardon me if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jenkins - a continuous integration (CI) platform.

Nexus - a repository manager.

You also tagged Maven so I guess in short Jenkins triggers Maven, Maven builds your packages, while doing it downloads dependencies from Nexus and also uploads artifacts back to Nexus.

Take Nexus as package repository to distribute your artifacts and Jenkins just as a build machine to build the artifacts.